# Socket.io - nodejs server side. transfer close after reconnection

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have two browser socket.io clients. For example. Client A and Client B and They are connected to Room one.

Following behavior is happening on my computer (installed nodejs 5, socket.io 1.4.5):
We suppose that both of clients are connected to Room One. When Client A is disconnected (lose connection) and reconnect after timeout and Client B does not use emit for send message to Room one, then original socket of Client A will be closed with transfer reason: timeouted. Thats good for me. I need it this behavior.

On other side:
When Client A is disconnected (lose connection) and reconnect in timeout time and Client B during that disconnected time uses emit for send message to Room one, then original socket of Client A after reconnect will be immediately closed with transfer reason: closed and not timeouted.

It looks that there is some behavior that selects disconnected sockets in timeout time for that some other online socket try emit message to same room.  When emited message cannot delivery to disconnected socket (on client side), then this socket is probably select for immediately close of transaction after reconnect in timeout time.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I think so. I solved it by other way. I added setTimeout for functions which are executed on disconnect event. By this way I can get data stored to variable from old socket to new socket, because during timeout a new socket take this data in limit of setTimeout function.

Comment: Do anybody know better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed futher issue. When mobile client lost connecting and somebody send emit to room where mobile client was connected, then mobile socket is disconnected immediately without timeout with reason transport close on linux.

the situation above is different for mac system. The socket is disconnected either timeout is gone or immediately if client mobile is reconnected.

Can anybody help what is a reason that this behaviors on same version of node (6.2) and same version of socket (1.4.6) are different?

Comment: Anybody don't know a solution? Really?